# Don't want Firebase running at first time

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

This is my source code.

```
ref.limitToLast(1).once('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
  console.log(childSnapshot.val() );
});
```

I really want it work only when I add new data to Firebase. Not at first time.

Comment: It's not currently possible, I think. But good question

Comment: That's too bad! TT

Comment: You can still ignore first value you get